# Room Count Query gives no result when ran on background thread

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I have an Android Application which uses [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). I need to check what are the counts of item inserted in my table so I have written following code in my Dao interface

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes")
int getCount();
```

In my repository class I have written the code something like below

```
public int deleteNote(final NoteEntity note) {
    final int[] count1 = new int[1];
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           count1[0] = mDb.schoolDao().getCount();
        }
    });

    return count1[0];
    }
```

Now when I call the above method in my `Activity`, I get the `count` as zero but when I force my application to run on the main thread i.e. removing the `Runnable` code, then it returns the valid `count`. I know firing any database query on the main thread is not a good option but I fail to understand why I get the count as zero when it runs on the background thread.

Just to be clear there is always data in the database.

Comment: Did you write a log to see after this line: `count = mDb.noteDao().getCount();`

Comment: @UmangBurman yes the log gets called

Comment: I meant Log for count? like `Log.d("Count: ", count);`

Comment: just to confirm, you did write the `log` inside the `run()` right?

Comment: If you are returning count from deleteNote function, it will always be 0. since the operation performed on separate thread later. For this purpose you could use some callback or put an observer.

Comment: @nupadhyaya will try and get back to u

Comment: Surely this can't be the actual code you're using? You're declaring `count` as `final` (and you forgot the type), and then assigning to it later? Even if it was in the same thread it wouldn't work since it's `final`. And obviously your current code wouldn't work even if `count` wasn't `final`, unless you're checking `count` after the `Runnable` has finished...

Comment: @UmangBurman I wrote a log in my runnable it gives the correct count but in my activity it gives zero

Comment: @nupadhyaya I wrote a log in my runnable it gives the correct count but in my activity it gives zero

Comment: @BadCash I have edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: @Nudge In Your activity it gives zero because you are not waiting for the call to get over, you are immediately printing the data which is the default value of int.

Comment: @UmangBurman How can i wait for the call?

Comment: Instead of using Executor... use AsyncTask, Do you want me to show you an example? @Nudge

Comment: @UmangBurman I thought Async Task and Executor does the same job. I will try with Async Task. Thanks

Comment: @Nudge It sure does the same job. i.e. Executing at the back, But Async will give you a callback, but this does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting 0 count because count1[0] returned earlier then actual DB query finished. Instead of using array use MutableLiveData. Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes") MutableLiveData< Integer> getCount();
```

Now you'll get MutableLiveData instance directly after code invocation, but you won't be able to use it right now because it's empty. What you need to do is subscribe on new data:

```
mDb.schoolDao().getCount(). observe (this, new Observer<Integer>() { @Override public void onChanged(@Nullable final Integer val {count[0]=val; }};
```

Note that you don't need to run this code in background. Just subscribe right after count [] initialisation and when DB return a count value onChanged() method would invoke.

Not sure that it's mistake but you're returning count [0] in method that returns void. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: will try and get back to you